# The Container view in docker desktop updates/flashes constantly

Tags: docker, docker-desktop, windows-11

The Container view in docker desktop keeps updating (i guess that is what it is doing anyway) which makes the window flash/reload about every second.
This makes it quite hard to work with the different containers since i hardly have time to click one before the window flashes/reloads again.

Anyone have a suggestion as to what causes this? And what i can do to make it go away?

I have tried to set "disableHardwareAcceleration": true in the settings.json file as i've seen suggested for other problems, but it didn't make a difference.

Thanks.